# Query Results For Consecutive Months In Column Grouped By Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

The following is sample data:

```
Name | Hours | RDate       | Company |
------------------------------------
A    |0      |2014-08-01   |W
A    |0      |2014-07-01   |W
A    |0      |2014-06-01   |W
A    |0      |2014-05-01   |W
B    |0      |2014-08-01   |X
C    |0      |2014-07-01   |Y
C    |0      |2014-06-01   |Y
D    |0      |2014-08-01   |V     
D    |0      |2014-07-01   |Z
```

The following are the results I desire:

```
Name | Hours | RDate       | Company |
------------------------------------
A    |0      |2014-08-01   |W
A    |0      |2014-07-01   |W
A    |0      |2014-06-01   |W
A    |0      |2014-05-01   |W
C    |0      |2014-07-01   |Y
C    |0      |2014-06-01   |Y
```

So the question is:

How do I get the results only of which `RDate` is consecutive months in the columns I.e `2014-08-01, 2014-07-01`(`2014-08-01, 2014-06-01` would not satisfy)for the same `name` and the same `company`

Comment: I'm fooling around with CTE but having a hard time figuring out what key words to use with it

Comment: Nice. I'm thinking you want a recursive CTE. Walk the rows and mark entries good if they meet your criteria, otherwise exclude them in the next either cte or final select.

Comment: Oh - I went to WPCarey too. Holler.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73117/discussion-between-michael-and-jeff-orris).

Comment: @Michael Can't  at work and chat is blocked by firewall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm thinking this is somewhat a variation of [**Grouping Islands of Contiguous Dates**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/71550/) problem.

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = DATEADD(MONTH, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Company ORDER BY RDate), RDate)
    FROM Test
)
,CteCount AS(
    SELECT *,
        CC = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Name, Company, RN)
    FROM Cte
)
SELECT
    Name, Hours, RDate, Company
FROM CteCount
WHERE CC > 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9cedb/1/0)

Comment: Excellent this works.  I thought I had a solutions in which I did a `SELF JOIN` on the `name` and `company` where  `DATEDIFF = 1` on the month and year` however the query has been running for 5 minutes now lol

Comment: just for sh**s and giggles I tried to figure this out on my own.  It works but takes forever.  Check out my answer.  FYI, I'm keeping your answer as marked because is way faster and you provided the answer first.  thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Although @wewesthemenace answers is way more efficient, I tried to figure out myself with solution I was working on and it works;  Keeping previously marked answer as marked because is way better.  This actually works as well:

```
SELECT 
    one.*
FROM 
    foo one 
INNER JOIN 
    foo two
ON 
    (one.Name = two.Name and one.Company = two.Company) 
WHERE
    CONVERT(int,FORMAT(two.Date, 'yyyyMM')) - CONVERT(int,FORMAT(one.ACSS_Date, 'yyyyMM')) = 1
ORDER BY
    one.Name
    ,one.Date DESC
```

Comment: Excellent:  I read the "Grouping Islands of Contiguous Dates " article.  Gave a lot of insight. Will read this one to :)